# How to update an object array every second in state?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to track the time for each todo in my app by saving it in an array of objects. I managed to make it work, but since I'm updating the state only when I stop the timer, the component is not displaying each second passing.

What would be the simplest way to update the state each second? I've tried for a few days (mainly with setInterval()) but I still can't make it work since it's a little beyond my knowledge.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // todos array of objects
      todos: null,
      // value to hold temp text input
      value: '',
    };
   ...
  }

  // start&stop timer + updating counters
  startTimer(todoKey) {
    const newTodos = this.state.todos.map(element => {
       if (element.key === todoKey) {
         if (element.status === "stopped") {
           return { ...element, status: 'started', startTime: new Date()};
         } else {
 
           let sessionSpent = new Date() - element.startTime; 
           let progress = element.goal !== null ? ((element.spent === null ? sessionSpent : element.spent + sessionSpent) * 1 / element.goal) : 1;    
 
           return { ...element, status: 'stopped', startTime: null, progress: progress, spent: element.spent === null ? sessionSpent : element.spent + sessionSpent };
         }
       } else { return element; }
     });
 
     this.setState({
       todos: newTodos
     });
  }

....
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that attempts to do anything about updating things every second. You mention `setInterval`. Can you show that attempt?

Comment: Altough not perfect, I found a solution. Please take a look at the answer below. Maybe you will be able to refine it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more trials, I managed to make it work.

I will leave it here if anyone is having the same problem, but be aware: I'm just starting, so it's possible that I'm doing a surgery with a hammer.

If that's the case, please suggest a better solution. Thank you.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //todos array of objects
      todos: null,
      //value to hold temp text input
      value: '',
      //timer status: need to save it outside of the setInterval() loop so it doesn't stop after 1 iteration.
      timerStatus: false,
      //setInterval function container
      interval: null,
      // active timer todoKey: saving it here so I can avoid that a timer is stopped by pressing another timer's button.
      activeTimer: null
    };
...
  }

  // start&stop timer + updating counters
  startTimer(todoKey) {
    // first I check that there's no active timer
    if (!this.state.timerStatus) {
    // if no timer is active, I save the active timer's key in the state(so I can forbid activities on the timer from another timer's button)
      this.setState({ activeTimer: todoKey });
    // here I start the setInterval() function in a variable and save it into a variable (so later I can save it in the state) 
      let interval = setInterval(() => {
    // looping through the array
        const newTodos = this.state.todos.map(element => {
          // finding the right object in the array so I can save the progress and the time spent, each second
          if (element.key === todoKey) {
            let sessionSpent = new Date() - element.startTime;
            let progress = element.goal !== null ? ((element.spent === null ? sessionSpent : element.spent + sessionSpent) * 1 / element.goal) : 1;
            return { ...element, status: 'started', startTime: new Date(), spent: element.spent + 1000, progress: progress }
          } else {
            return element;
          }
        });
        this.setState({
          todos: newTodos
        });
      }, 1000);
      // setting the timerStatus as true(so I can have a trouth source outside of the loop when I need to stop it) 
      // saving the variable containint setInterval() in the state (so I can use clearInterval() from the else block
      this.setState({ timerStatus: true, interval: interval });
      console.log(this.state.timerStatus);

    } else {
      // checking if the pressed button is the one belonging to the active timer
      if (todoKey === this.state.activeTimer) {
        // saving in the state the timer's status (thus making possible for another timer to start
        // clearing the setInterval() function
        this.setState({ timerStatus: false, interval: clearInterval(this.state.interval) }); 
        // looping through the array to save the current progress
        const newTodos = this.state.todos.map(element => {
          if (element.key === todoKey) {
            let sessionSpent = new Date() - element.startTime; 
            let progress = element.goal !== null ? ((element.spent === null ? sessionSpent : element.spent + sessionSpent) * 1 / element.goal) : 1;   
            return { ...element, status: 'stopped', startTime: null, progress: progress, spent: element.spent === null ? sessionSpent : element.spent + sessionSpent };
          } else {
            return element;
          }
        }
        );
        // updating the state 
        this.setState({
          todos: newTodos
        });
      } else {
        // showing an error Toast when user tries to start another timer if there's one already active (when the check (todoKey === this.state.activeTimer) is false)
        Toast.show("A timer is already running and multitasking is bad D:", Toast.LONG);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example:

```
this.setInterval( () => { 
       let d = new Date();
       let result = d.getHours() + d.getMinutes() / MINUTES_IN_HOUR;
       this.setState({
           timeLineTop: result
       })
    }, 1000);
```